# difference between page load with and without developer tools

Tags: javascript, html

What difference does it make when we open a web-page with developer tools open? page loads properly when developer tool is open not otherwise.

this issue is on IE11, page loads fine on chrome and I am targeting iframe

Comment: Can you give some more specs,like which browser are you running the application in and what is there in your application..

Comment: I am facing issue on IE11. page loads fine on chrome and I am referencing iframe.

Comment: That is a common issue in IE11 if at all your application is using `console.log` or any of the `console` object for that matter.[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Browser_compatibility)